# Javascript Fetch API not showing results on multiple cards

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a script that fetches the data from a link and then inserts that in tables and shows it to the user. the script worked fine. but then I decided to make the function more dynamic so I added 2 arguments name and Html div name where the data will display. it worked fine when I called the function the first time but it doesn't show any data on the second call. I'm using PHP for my projects and new to javascript. but I made a similar function in PHP but that works. any suggestions?

```js
function getInfoByCountry(name, displayName) {
  fetch("https://something.com/countries/" + name)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      output = `
      <tr>
        <td>Total Cases</td>
        <td>${data.cases}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Today Cases</td>
        <td>${data.todayCases}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Deaths</td>
        <td>${data.deaths}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Recovered</td>
        <td>${data.recovered}</td>
      </tr>        
      <tr>
        <td>Critical</td>
        <td>${data.critical}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Active Cases</td>
        <td>${data.active}</td>
      </tr>                        
    `;
      document.getElementById(displayName).innerHTML = output;
    });
}

getInfoByCountry("USA", "USAInfo");

getInfoByCountry("China", "ChinaInfo");
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped mb-0">
    <tbody id="ChinaInfo">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Dont you need asecond `<tbody id='USAInfo'>`

Comment: Yes, to show the output in the table

Comment: The problem is here it can find ChinaInfo but not USAInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return` like this

```
 function getInfoByCountry(name, displayName) {
  var display = document.getElementById(displayName);
  return fetch("https://smthing.com/countries/"+name)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {

      output = `
  <tr>
    <td>Total Cases</td>
    <td>${data.cases}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Today Cases</td>
    <td>${data.todayCases}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Deaths</td>
    <td>${data.deaths}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Recovered</td>
    <td>${data.recovered}</td>
  </tr>        
  <tr>
    <td>Critical</td>
    <td>${data.critical}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Active Cases</td>
    <td>${data.active}</td>
  </tr>                        
`;

  document.getElementById(displayName).innerHTML += output;

    }

    );
}


  getInfoByCountry("USA", "display");

  getInfoByCountry("China", "display");
```

Comment: Right, functions don't return anything by default I knew that but I wonder how it worked for the first time?

Comment: with the second edit, it shows `[object Promise]` instead of data

Comment: still doesn't show the data instead shows `[object Promise]` any idea why?

Comment: May I have the api url to test it from my end

Comment: I have updated the answer here. This would show both country data

Comment: Please remove the API URL form the answer thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the result using `displayName` as id attribute, you should add another one for `USAinfo` as mentioned in the comments, or a better implementation would be to create the table dynamically and append the result to the container.

```js
function getInfoByCountry(name, displayName) {
  fetch("API_URL" + name)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      output = `
      <table class="table table-striped mb-0">
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>Total Cases</td>
        <td>${data.cases}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Today Cases</td>
        <td>${data.todayCases}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Deaths</td>
        <td>${data.deaths}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Recovered</td>
        <td>${data.recovered}</td>
      </tr>        
      <tr>
        <td>Critical</td>
        <td>${data.critical}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Active Cases</td>
        <td>${data.active}</td>
      </tr>
       </tbody>
  </table><hr />
    `;
      document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += output;
    });
}

getInfoByCountry("USA", "USAInfo");

getInfoByCountry("China", "ChinaInfo");
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="table-responsive">
  
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but Omolewa answered first. can you please remove the API URL form the answer.

Comment: Sure, will remove it now

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add `return` statement for returning output.

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/zxk37pvb/2/) is fiddle you can check function.

```
function getInfoByCountry(name,displayName) {
    debugger;
  return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"+name)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      output = `
      <tr>
        <td>Total Cases</td>
        <td>${data.title}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Today Cases</td>
        <td>${data.body}</td>
      </tr>
    `;
      document.getElementById(displayName).innerHTML = output;
    });
}
```

Comment: @lachiweb you can create multiple cards also as per your data length. may be [this](https://jsfiddle.net/t9gxe0j1/1/) fiddle helps you :)